# Why is useFetcher causing an re-render infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

I have an input. On every change to the input, I want to call an API.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
  // updated by input
  const [urlText, setUrlText] = useState("");

  const fetcher = useFetcher();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (urlText === "" || !fetcher) return;
    fetcher.load(`/api/preview?url=${urlText}`);
  }, [urlText]);
```

The issue is, when I put `urlText` inside of the dependencies array, there is an infinite rendering loop, and React claims the issue is I might be updating state inside of the `useEffect`. However, as far as I can tell, I'm not updating any state inside of the hook, so I'm not sure why an infinite re-render is happening.

Any thoughts?

The fuller version of the code is:

*Note:* The  bug still happens without the debounce, or the `useMemo`, all of that stuff is roughly irrelevant.

```
export default function () {
  const { code, higlightedCode } = useLoaderData<API>();

  const [urlText, setUrlText] = useState("");
  const url = useMemo(() => getURL(prefixWithHttps(urlText)), [urlText]);
  const debouncedUrl = useDebounce(url, 250);

  const fetcher = useFetcher();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (url === null || !fetcher) return;
    fetcher.load(`/api/preview?url=${encodeURIComponent(url.toString())}`);
  }, [debouncedUrl]);

  return (
             <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Paste URL"
            className={clsx(
              "w-full rounded-sm bg-gray-800 text-white text-center placeholder:text-white"
              //"placeholder:text-left text-left"
            )}
            value={urlText}
            onChange={(e) => setUrlText(e.target.value)}
          ></input>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full version of this component? You might update your state somewhere else.

Comment: @RyanLe done, i'll make a stackblitz too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're having is that fetcher is updated throughout the fetch process. This is causing your effect to re-run, and since you are calling `load` again, it is repeating the cycle.

You should be checking `fetcher.state` to see when to fetch.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // check to see if you haven't fetched yet
  // and we haven't received the data
  if (fetcher.state === 'idle' && !fetcher.data) {
    fetcher.load(url)
  }
}, [url, fetcher.state, fetcher.data])
```

https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#usefetcher

Comment: won't `fetcher.data` always be set after the first successful load?

Comment: Also, I might be a bit silly here -- but this will wait for the previous request to finish firing, right? Presumably, I might want to just cancel / ignore the result of the previous request and start firing a new one

Comment: If you call fetcher.load again while the fetcher is in progress, it will cancel the current fetch before sending a new request.

Comment: The `useEffect` here is for initial render. If you want to fetch again, you'd most likely call `fetcher.load` from an event handler. This will cancel any pending fetchers and clear the data before fetching again.

Comment: The link provided is no longer valid (404).

Answer (score 2):

You might by setting state in `useFetcher` hook, please check code of `load` method from `useFetcher`.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I'm silly. `useDebounce` returns an array.